# How do I get the YARN application ID from within a Mapper?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

How do I get a yarn application ID from within a mapper? It looks like I can get the CONTAINER_ID from an environment variable with the same name, and it looks like the format of the containerID is similar to the application ID, but it is not the same. Is there a better way to do this?

```
>>> sc.applicationId
'application_1531947999592_0024'
>>> sc.parallelize([1]).map(lambda v:os.environ['CONTAINER_ID']).collect()
['container_1531947999592_0024_01_000008']
>>>
```